# just a question regarding passwords .computing the possibilities for a numerical PIN

Tags: passwords

How many possibilities for a numerical PIN with exactly 9 digits? How
about a PIN with no more than 9 digits?

Comment: This is a basic mathematic question. It might have been better suited on math.SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a basic math question.

Answer (score 2):

For a PIN of length 9, you have exactly `10^9 = 1000000000` combinations (which can be brute-forced by a computer in less than one second). That's 29.9 bits of entropy.

For a PIN of at most 9 digits, you have exactly `10^9 + 10^8 + ... + 10^1 = 1111111110` combinations, which is not that greater than the previous answer. That's 30.0 bits of entropy.